# Check Alphanumeric of specific size UIMA RUTA

Tags: regex, uima, ruta

I am new to UIMA RUTA.
I am trying to implement a basic task which should match Alphanumeric characters of specific size.
Eg:
**123Abcd**

I tried the below code:

```
DECLARE VarA;
ANY{REGEXP("([A-Za-z0-9]{7})")->MARK(VarA)};
```

It's not working as expected.
Please let me know what I am doing wrong.
The same REGEX is working in other REGEX engine except in RUTA.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

This is because Ruta split up the document in small fragments/tokens/Basic Annotations (see [this](https://uima.apache.org/d/ruta-current/tools.ruta.book.html#ugr.tools.ruta.language.seeding)). The default seeder implementation splits up words if they are a combination of a number and characters. The default seeder implementation can be changed by your own seeder with a different behaviour.

Your example "123Abcd" will be parsed to the following tokens (not all levels are in the list - see link for more information):

```
Document -> Complete document "123Abcd"
NUM -> 123
CW -> Abcd
```

Another example of input "45 abcd 5" becomes:

```
Document -> Complete document "45 abcd 5"
NUM -> 45
SPACE -> The spacer between 45 and abcd // Not visible by default
SW -> abcd
SPACE -> The spacer between abcd and 5 // Not visible by default
NUM -> 5
```

In your example you try to match the regular expression to the Any tokens. The document contains 2 Any tokens (NUM and CW) and because that the pattern doesn't match (it's not 1 token but splitted up)

You can do things like the following example to get the correct results:

```
DECLARE VarA, VarB, VarC, VarD;

// Option 1 (execute regex on the complete input document
// I think this is not a good solution because this can be slow
Document{REGEXP("([A-Za-z0-9]{7})") -> MARK(VarA)};

// Option 2 (match with regex on each annotation type)
(NUM{REGEXP("[0-9]{3}")} CW{REGEXP("[a-zA-Z]{4}")}){ -> MARK(VarB)};

// Option 3 (first match a pattern of annotations and then match the 
// regex on the complete pattern)
(NUM CW){REGEXP("([A-Za-z0-9]{7})") -> MARK(VarC)};

// Option 4 (only check if its a "number + capital word")
(NUM CW){ -> MARK(VarD)};
```

Comment: Wow..thats a very good explanation and thank u for that.
I tried to write a annotation for below example:

Comment: Eg: SS-SSS-ABC
S is alphanumeric.
'-' and spaces are allowed, i.e., SS SSSS ABC is also valid.
my code:
DECLARE VarA;
DECLARE VarB;
Document{->RETAINTYPE(SPACE)};
(W|NUM)(W|NUM|SPECIAL|SPACE)*{-> MARK(VarA,1,2)};
VarA{REGEXP("([A-Z0-9]{2,3}[-]{0,1}[A-Z0-9]{4}[-]{0,1}([IBC]){3})")->MARK(EntityType};
Doubt 1: The above code doesn't detect multiple patterns
input: SS-SSS-ABC , SS SSSS ABC 
Output : SS SSSSSSS ABC
It doesn't detect the first value with '-'
Input: SS SSS ABC is policy number.
Output: unassigned.
So, it is detecting/ comparing with last words.
How can I make it work?